# Plotly.Net offline use

Tags: f#, plotly.net

Is it possible to run Plotly.Net offline with F#?

You can store "plotly-2.6.3.min.js" and "require.min.js" locally and replace paths to html/javascript and see graphs. But when using Geo Maps, how to handle with world_50m or world_110m.json as needed also to draw a map?

For example first "baseMapOnly" from here https://plotly.net/05_0_geo-vs-mapbox.html and world_110m.json downloaded and pointed to GeoJson:

```
open Plotly.NET

// world_110m.json stored locally 
let geoJsondata =
  IO.File.ReadAllText("world_110m.json")
  |> JsonConvert.DeserializeObject

let baseMapOnly = 
    Chart.PointGeo(GeoJson = geoJsondata, locations = [])
    |> Chart.withMarginSize(0,0,0,0)
     ....

baseMapOnly
|> Chart.show
```

Also "https://cdn.plot.ly" and "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.6" of generated html replaced to local paths of "plotly-2.6.3.min.js" and "require.min.js".

When I try to render a map plot, there is still a call to https://cdn.plot.y/world_110m.json even though paths changed to html file.

What is wrong? Is there some other place to add local path?

Comment: Do you have a code sample?

Comment: topojsonURL not implemented to Plotly.Net Config, any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

The latest version (4.0.0) should cover your bases. The Config object was fully implemented, meaning you can now set `TopojsonURL`, and there is also an option to fully include plotly.js in the html head by setting `PlotlyJSReference = Full` on the chart's DisplayOptions, meaning the document is truly offline:

```fs
Chart.PointGeo(GeoJson = geoJsondata, locations = [])
|> Chart.withConfigStyle(
    TopojsonURL = "your-url-here"
)
|> Chart.withDisplayOptionsStyle(
    PlotlyJSReference = Full
)
|> Chart.show
```

Comment: Many thanks! This is exactly what I was hoping for.